# I do not want my Userform to retain its values

Tags: vba, userform

I have created a userform that has a textbox which requires an input of numbers, however when I add invalid characters I have coded the form to give an error message and to reset the form. The problem is after error message when people put the right characters in the boxes, the userform has retained the old characters (that do not work) and is trying to caclulate with those. Im not sure if my question is understandable or not. I appreciate any help

```
ErrorCheckAmount:
If Amount = "" Then
    MsgBox "Your Have Entered Invalid Characters, Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Unload UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show
ElseIf IsNumeric(Amount) Then
    GoTo ErrorCheckQuantity
Else
    MsgBox "Your Have Entered Invalid Characters, Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Unload UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show
End If

ErrorCheckQuantity:
If Quantity = "" Then
     MsgBox "Your Have Entered Invalid Characters, Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Unload UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show
ElseIf IsNumeric(Quantity) Then
    GoTo Start
Else
    MsgBox "Your Have Entered Invalid Characters, Please Try Again", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    Unload UserForm1
    UserForm1.Show
End If
```

Comment: Where is this code?  In your userform?  Needs a bit more context to understand exactly what's going on here.  Typically it's not a good approach to use Goto for flow control - we have other options for that, and Goto is best reserved for error handling purposes.

Comment: Also consider showing a new instance of the userform, i.e. `With New UserForm1`, `.Show`. It's a bit technical, but [this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) explains why.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that you want to DELETE the user's input and make them start over.  I think it would be better to leave their input and let them remove the invalid characters (maybe tell them what you're considering invalid ... should they only include numbers?  or just don't use special characters?).   So - that solves your immediate problem by just deleting the unload / show commands!

If you really want to delete the user's input - I'd recommend only deleting the text boxes where they entered invalid data ... so - for Quantity - you could just set the [textboxname].value = "" instead of form unload and show.

If you want to be 100% certain that the form will be empty when your user opens it - you could add code to the Initialize procedure to clear the values.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
    txtAmount.Value = ""
    txtQuantity.Value = 0
end sub
```

Tim Williams makes a great comment - that the code you posted doesn't provide enough context for a full answer. But - I think one of the three approaches above should work for you.

Comment: I like the first idea, that makes sense. do you know how I would be able to put them back on the userform with their original data still on it?